# Condition that shows when there are elements in $[G,G]$ which are not commutator.(Looking for a proof)

Tags: group-theory, derived-subgroup

It's known that for a given group $G$ and the derived subset $[G,G]$ it's not true that every element of $[G,G]$ is a commutator. I've seen a condition that shows when there are elements in $[G,G]$ which are not commutator.

> For any group $G$ with
> $$\left|\left[G:Z\left(G\right)\right]\right|^{2}<\left|\left[G,G\right]\right|$$
> there are elements in $[G,G]$ that are not commutator.

I have not seen any proof of this, it would be really nice if someone proof that or give me a link about the problem.

Comment: Note this question was neither downvoted nor voted to close....

Answer (score 4):

Since $[gk_1,gk_2] = [g,h]$ for all $k_1,k_2 \in Z(G)$, there are at most $[G:Z(G)]^2$ distinct commutators.

So if $[G:Z(G)]^2 < |[G,G]|$ then $|[G,G]|$ is larger than the number of commutators, so there must be elements of $[G,G]$ that are not commutators.

Comment: In your responses to answers and comments, you are continually saying things like "How do you know (some claim or other)?" when nobody made that claim. Perhaps that is why you attract downvotes. I did not say that the number of distinct commutators is given by $|G:Z(G)]^2$, I said that it was at most that. And I explained exactly why that is true, so why are you asking me to explain? (In fact, since commutators with the identity and those of form $[g,g]$ are trivial, you can get a slightly better upper bound than this.)